# How to debug java.lang.NullException error in iReport (JasperReport) using javafx in netbeans with MS SQL Server Database

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm creating a report, basically for my project using Netbeans IDE 8.2, JasperReport 6.0.0 and iReport 5.6.0 (actually tried the JasperReport 6.2.0, but unluckily same results occur).

I can preview the result, but unfortunately whenever I tried to save the .jrxml file. I've got an error called java.lang.NullPointerException

I've searched for a solution from the internet and tried every solution I thought would help, but I still ended posting here.

Here is the stack trace.

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlEditorSupport$3.run(JrxmlEditorSupport.java:267)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)`

I expect the output of user input and its data from SQL Server Database.

Comment: This is an error inside ireport correct?

Comment: [mcve] please .

Comment: @kleopatra that will probably be difficult, seems like a problem in the ireport installation.

Comment: @PetterFriberg difficult or not, that's what needs to be done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in iReport see [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241404).

User kizinfo found this work around.

> after previewing (which saves the report successfully) just close and reopen the document before making any additional changes (so you can save it).

## *but*

iReport is the old IDE it's  supported in maintenance-only mode [ended December 31, 2015](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer), probably you are better of switching to the latest IDE [JasperSoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio)

Comment: @MichaelCastillo Why don't you switch to JasperSoft Studio?, there is a community version for free.

Comment: After reading your answer. It came to my interest this JasperSoft Studio, I think it worth trying for. Would you give me a link on how to install it properly?

Comment: @MichaelCastillo https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio/releases

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, but after reading so many errors alike from another forum, I figure out how to make this work.

First I change the **Filter Expression** value in the Reports property to *new Boolean(true)* and the value of **When No Data** to *All Sections, No Detail* I don't know how and why it has to do with the Filter Expression, but YES it works fine right now . I can pass values to its parameters.